# Trying to extend header div to fit a page

Tags: css

I'm trying to extend my header width to fit the whole page with this code is my external CSS:

```
.header{
 padding: 25px;
 background-color: black;}
```

But whenever I enter a new value of pixels, say 50px, the header extends downwards instead of left and right like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

50px to what? The padding? Did you try setting the width to 100%?

```
.header{width:100%}
```